# Promise returning a promise instead of data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

There are a lot of similar questions but none of them really works when I test them so I don't think Im understanding them well. I modeled the below after [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).Is there a way the following to return 3?

```
const fn = () => {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);
  });

  promise.then(function(result) {
    return result * 2;
  });

  return promise
}

fn()
```

Comment: Why is it surprising that `return promise` returns a promise?

Comment: It will always return a promise

Comment: Any way i can return 3?

Comment: It runs asynchronously, it returns before the calculation is done.

Comment: `fn().then(result => console.log(result))`

Comment: still returning a promise